# React Native responsive height of image

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

On my screen I want my image to take 100% of width and minimum amount of height required to remain in resizeMode={'contain'}.How can I achieve this.

Comment: Do you know the dimensions of your image?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-flex-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-flex-image)

You can use as (example)

```
 <FlexImage style={{ width : '100%'}} source={require('../assets/image.jpg')} />
```